# "Not a statement" issue with 2d character array java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have a 2d char array of a map, where each position in the array refers to the character in that position in the map. I also have the user's current position. I have checked my map contains values and that the position is correct and that I am not trying to reach anything out of bounds in the map. For some reason my n = map[....], e =... etc isn't working and comes back with the error 'not a statement' and '; needed' etc. I cannot see why this would not work. Any ideas?

```
 public String look(int[] position, char[][] mapArray)
    {
    char[][] map = mapArray;
    char n;
    char e;
    char s;
    char w;
    int across;
    int down;
    across = position[0];
    down = position[1];
    System.out.println(across);
    System.out.println(down);
    n = map[(down + 1),across];
    e = map[down, (across + 1)];
    s = map[(down - 1), across];
    w = map[down, (across - 1)];
    //System.out.println("Across" + across);
    //System.out.println("Down" + down);
    //System.out.println("N" + n);
    //System.out.println("E" + e);
    //System.out.println("S" + s);
    //System.out.println("W" + w);
    return "hello";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
 n = map[(down + 1)][across];
```

Comment: Thanks, what a stupid question! Will pick you as soon as I can for best answer.

Answer (score 2):

To access a 2d array you need:

```
n = map[(down + 1)][across]
```

instead of

```
n = map[(down + 1),across]
```

[same goes for the other 2d array accesses]

The idea is: `map[(down + 1)]` gives you a `char[]`, and then you access this `char[]` like any array [and thus you use two `[]`]

Answer (score 0):

This should be:

```
n = map[(down + 1)][across];
```